# Excel giving error when using ROUND

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I type in the number 1,234.5678 in cell A1
I type in the formula =round(A1, 1)

And get this error:
[image]

(my , and . are switched because of European/Asian standards - could that be the reason you think?)

I tried =sum(round(A1,1)) and any other variation I could think of, all give the same error.

I tried to switch , and . to American standard, and I used ROUND instead of round.  Still same error

[image]

Comment: Did you try `=ROUND(A1,1)` - with capital letters ?

Comment: Yes I just tried that - and I even switched the . and , to be American standard to see...  still same error (updated my question with new image)

Comment: To avoid confusion, don’t include the thousands separator. That won’t necessarily solve the problem, but it may help to isolate. FYI: case doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=ROUND(A1;1)
```

as the comma is often swapped with a semi colon on some systems.

Comment: YES!!! - That was it haha - Thanks Mike - I had no idea that you could use ";" there.  I guess it makes sense, otherwise how would you do a ROUND(123,456.789,1)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use 
        =ROUND(A1,2)

And make sure that columns are numbers in format.